# Passing entityform field data to an API in Drupal-7

Tags: php, drupal-7

I had a look across stack overflow and, to my knowledge this has not been answered here. Perhaps because it's simple and most people already know the answer.

I'm new to Drupal and I need to take data captured from an entityform and push it through to an API. The API part is easy, I am unfamiliar with how to access Drupal entity form data.

Could anyone push me in the right direction?

Comment: We need more information , what do you want to do ? submit form to api when you try to create a new entity ?

Comment: @Fky, thanks for the reply. Yes, the API will essentially create a contact based off of the information submitted in the form, so I need the info from each of the fields in order to create said contact. Does that clarify at all?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand all you need but  :

1 : Grab all form into drupal , use hook_form_alter

2 : Add a custom submit function to process

3 : Contact and send your api via custom submit

so ,

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x

```
// Step 1
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id == 'my_wanted_form_id'){
     $form['#submit'][] = '_my_custom_callback'; // Step 2
  }
  // if you don't know the form_id , you can dump $form_id and see it when your are on form
}
```

Step 3 :

```
function _my_custom_callback($form, &$form_state){
  $values = $form_state['values'];

  // all values inserted into form are into $values
  // make your call to api with curl or whatever you want
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sending this through, I'll give it a go! I've since abandoned the project but I'll give it a look and let you know. Sorry for the extremely late reply. Been tied up for a long while.